# Outlook 2003 toolbar customization: add/edit button list

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I have macros in my `VbaProject.OTM` file. A new toolbar is created when Outlook is launched to allow users to easily run the macros.

[image: Outlook Toolbar]

(sorry about the interface being in French ;-))

I would like users to be able to customize the toolbar by removing some of its buttons or adding them back. Here is the customization panel:

[image: Outlook Toolbar Customization panel]

All my macros are there (all the public `Sub()s` in modules). However, the macro names and icons aren't really user friendly. I'm looking for a way to change both the icons and names. I'm actually using default *FaceIds* for my toolbar buttons (but I will add some custom icons in the future too). Also, if there would be a way for some public `Sub()s` to not me showed there, it would be perfect. Or to add a whole category instead of the *Macros* category.

When searching through the Web, all I can find is how to add toolbar buttons (which is already done in my example). Does anyone have any idea on how to edit the names/icons in the toolbar Customization panel? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest built-in dialog boxes cannot be modified with VBA.

Try adding a permanent button "Add/delete buttons" to the toolbar, to launch a userform to choose the specific macros you want users to work with. You could then use a better name and other text to describe the macros in your own listbox.

Comment: It sounds like a great alternative. The only problem I have adding/removing buttons is about the %appdata%/Microsoft/Outlook/outcmd.dat file growing forever and slowing down the whole application. This file contains all the toolbars customizations, deleting it each time would also remove all the modifications manually done by the user.